# Remove Array of UIButtons in Swift

Tags: arrays, loops, swift, uibutton

I'm looking for a way to remove an array of buttons created in Swift.

My project is a game of anagrams where a word is broken down into its letters, shuffled, and then shown in buttons. That works very well with the code below.

The only thing is that I'd like to remove the buttons before showing a new word, so they don't overlap (makes for bad UI). So my quest is this:

1. Check if the characterArray that holds the letters is empty, or nil
2. If nil, then load new word
3. If a word is already there, then remove the buttons (the word) before adding the new buttons (word)

```
@IBAction func shuffleString() { 
    txtFileArray = fileContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

    // 1. Shuffle the plist with the words to form anagrams from
    currentQuestion = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(txtFileArray.count)))
    anagramString = txtFileArray.objectAtIndex(currentQuestion) as String

    var staticY: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.size.height / 9 * 1; // Static X for all buttons.
    var staticWidth: CGFloat = 46; // Static Width for all Buttons.
    var staticHeight: CGFloat = 46; // Static Height for all buttons.

    var staticPadding: CGFloat = 10; // Padding to add between each button.
    var characters: String? = anagramString

    // 2. Initialize the buttons for the letters
    var button = UIButton()

    // 3. Add the word to the characterArray
    var characterArray = Array(anagramString)

    /* HERE I NEED CONDITIONAL STATEMENT AS DESCRIBED IN MY QUESTION: */
    /* CHECK IF CHARACTERARRAY IS EMPTY, IF NOT REMOVE THE CURRENT BUTTONS */
    /* BEFORE ADDING NEW ONES */
    for (index, value) in enumerate(characterArray) {

        button.removeFromSuperview() // THE BUTTONS ARE NOT REMOVED
        println("Clear Tiles")
        println("index: \(index) and value: \(value)")
    }

    // 4. Add the word from the characterArray to corresponding amount of buttons
    for (index, value) in enumerate(characterArray) /* randomIndex */ {

        button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
        button.frame.origin.x = (CGFloat(index) * 45.0) + 100.0
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"Tile.png"), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitle("\(value)", forState: .Normal)

        buttonSeriesArray.append(button)

        self.view.addSubview(button)
       // println("index: \(index) and value: \(value)")
    }

    println(characterArray)

}
```

Comment: It rather looks like you are asking for a complex strategy to develop your game than actually removing buttons which is fairly straight forward.

Comment: Well, perhaps. But this code works well and I'm justing looking for a way to remove the buttons for each new word that is shown. If you look at the first enumeration: that is where the buttons should be removed but they are not. Any ideas on this would be very helpful.

Comment: You should have written that in your question. Sorry, can't take back the down vote.

Comment: Instead of removing the button, why not just make it invisible (.hidden). That's what I do in such circumstances.

Comment: That's okay Thomas :) Acutally I did write that I want the buttons removed: Look at the 3rd line in the question. But the problem is the 'button.removeFromSuperview()' method does nothing to the buttons. Each array of buttons are added on top of the others. Is it my 'for loop' that is wrong?

Comment: @Thomas "Sorry, can't take back the down vote" - You can. Click it again.

Comment: It says: I can't up vote my own post. Oops, that was a comment from David to Thomas

Comment: I think my problem is related to this loop (SEE also the original post for context). It doesn't remove the buttons: for (index, value) in enumerate(characterArray) {
            
            button.removeFromSuperview()
            button.hidden = true
          
        }

Comment: @David: No. It tells me it is locked. Works only for a few minutes or so. Well...

Comment: -- Ah, unless the question is edited. So @Borges: edit the question as above and I'll take it back.

Comment: @Thomas: ok. Is it more clearer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is simply broken. First you create a button and then you remove it from superview, but it is not assigned to any. And you do that in a loop.

Comment: Not sure about adding the same button object more than once to the same view. Does not seem to make sense too. I guess you want multiple button instances.

Comment: I can see your points of view. But as I wrote in the question: The function should first check if the array, characterArray, that holds the letters is empty. If it is, don't remove the buttons because they are not there. BUT if the array already has letters in it then remove the last letters before adding the new ones. I hope this makes sense now.

Comment: Yes. I'll explain in more detail later since I have to leave for some hours now...

Comment: One problem remains : to remove the buttons you should point to. But it is not the case actually, your button variable in not bounded to any button in the view actually! You should have a kind of list of current buttons in the view and peek a button in it one at a time.

Comment: But I thought I did that since I declared and initialized the button varible BEFORE the 'for loops'. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to make a `[UIButton]` and make that an instance variable. You have only one `UIButton` object. Again: to achieve what you want create those buttons once in `awakeFromNib` and change their contents at runtime, resp. make them hide or show. Your whole programming has a wrong concept. Try with a single button first. Then go on with a button array.

Comment: Ok. I've made a little progress. I made a single button as you suggested Thomas and was able to remove it. But when I move on to the array I run into problems. I instantiate the `button` variable in `viewDidLoad` and then in my `enumeration for loop` of the `characterArray` the buttons are created as normal. But now the `enumeration for loop` for the `buttonSeriesArray` removes only the last button of the word.

Comment: If you really are stuck with that you should open a new question. SO is intended to deliver one answer to one question.

Comment: @Thomas: This is a late reply but JBY helped me out in email and this code removes the buttons before adding a new set: `for var i = 0; i < buttonSeriesArray.count; ++i {
            button = buttonSeriesArray[i];
            button.removeFromSuperview();
        }`. BTW, thanks for voting my questions up :)

Comment: You could shorten that to `for button in buttonSeriesArray { button.removeFromSuperView() }`. No problem with taking the down vote back after you made the question clear :-) But what means JBY?

Comment: You're right Thomas, just tested it and that works too. JBY is short for  Jean-Baptiste Yunès who posted a comment earlier.

Comment: Ah - lol. Never would have guesses and Google returned funny things for that acronym. Would be nice if you tick the "Correct answer" :-)